# Click webview inflated crash

Tags: android, webview

I'm trying to inflate a webview in my application. When i click the browser start but the app crash :
The webview finish to load and after that the app is crashing

```
viewGroup = (ViewGroup)activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content);

        activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        final TextView textViewCompteur ;
        ImageView ic_close ;

        final View inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.interstitial_ads, null, true);

        webView = (WebView)inflater.findViewById(R.id.webViewSplashAds);
        ic_close = (ImageView)inflater.findViewById(R.id.imageViewCloseSplashAds);
        textViewCompteur = (TextView)inflater.findViewById(R.id.textViewSplashAds);

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); 
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setClickable(true);

        webView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        AppehourTools.disableAdsScroll(webView);

        // icone de fermeture
        ic_close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                viewGroup.removeView(inflater);
                activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
                showBar();

            }
        });

        webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        webView.loadData("<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">body{margin:0 auto;text-align:center;}</style></head><body>"
                + array.get(0).getUrl()
                + "</body></html>", "text/html", "utf8");
        Log.d("AppehourInterstitialAds", "showing ad");


        hideBar();

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                int delayClose;
                delayClose = Integer.valueOf(array.get(0).getValidDelay());
                viewGroup.addView(inflater);


                new CountDownTimer(delayClose * 1000, 1000) {

                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                        textViewCompteur.setText(millisUntilFinished / 1000
                                + " "
                                + context.getString(R.string.seconds_remaining));

                    }

                    public void onFinish() {

                        viewGroup.removeView(inflater);
                        activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
                        showBar();
                    }
                }.start();
            }


            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                hideBar();
                viewGroup.removeView(inflater);
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                //i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                activity.startActivity(i);

                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);

            }
        });
    }
```

And the error :

```
03-31 09:39:14.278: W/System.err(1825): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=air.com.goodgamestudios.empirefourkingdoms&referrer=mat_click_id=c5e82ec15ac735af3b-20140331-4066 }
```

Can you help me ? 
Thank you

Comment: you need the market application installed for that url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running this app on the emulator, the app will crash since the "Play Store" app is not installed on it. Make sure your device has play store installed before running this.